# Replace values from json file with ones in a text file

Tags: java, json

I have 2 files, I want to replace all the values in the JSON file with ones from the new file.

My JSON format is something like:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "",
 "code": 9.3
 },

 {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Test",
 "code": 5.0
 },
```

My .txt file is:

```
1 - 9.9
2 - 3.4
```

etc

So for all ids in the json file equal to the 1st number in the text file I want to replace "code" with the 2nd number in the line, which is inside the .txt file.

Comment: What programming language? This would be trivial in Python for example.

Comment: using which programming language ?

Comment: The JSON file should contain an array. There should be `[ ... ]` around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

-> Read JSON values from file:-

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("input1.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    String id= (String) jsonObject.get("id");
```

-> Read input values from text file:-

```
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(new File(input2.txt));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    String s; 
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
      String[] strArr=s.split("-"); //split each element of input text file to get id and value individually
                .
                .
     }
```

-> compare ids and write updated values to new JSON file

```
       JSONObject objWr = new JSONObject();
       if(id.equals(strArr[0].trim())){
       objWr.put("id", id);
       objWr.put("code", strArr[1]); //replace code with 2nd element in String[] from txt file
       }
       FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("output.json");
       fw.write(objWr.toJSONString());
       fw.flush();
```

Note:- In many places I have missed closing i/o streams, and enclosing try-catch blocks which I leave for you to fill in , hope this helps.